How to specify extensions as a variable in a file loop?
In the following code, how do I put the "extension" part as a variable? Ideally something like extensions_supported=docx,doc,pdf.
for file in "$folder/"*.{docx,doc,pdf}; do
    process "$file"
done


You are on the right track. Read about parameter expansion in Bash manual (or type man bash on your terminal and scroll down until the "PARAMETER EXPANSION" section). Also read about brace expansion.

$ folder='tmp'
$ shopt -s extglob
$ extensions_supported='docx|doc|pdf'
$ for file in "$folder/"*.@($extensions_supported); do
     echo process "$file"
  done
process tmp/bar.doc
process tmp/etc.docx
process tmp/foo.docx
process tmp/that.doc
process tmp/this.pdf

Remove the echo when done testing.
The above was run on this input:
$ ls tmp
bad.txt  bar.doc  etc.docx  foo.docx  that.doc  this.pdf


$ ls /tmp/dir
a.doc  b.docx  c.pdf

$ d='/tmp/dir';e='doc,docx,pdf';for f in `eval echo "$d/"*.{"$e"}`;do echo "$f";done
/tmp/dir/a.doc
/tmp/dir/b.docx
/tmp/dir/c.pdf

eval in the "POSIX Programmer's Manual": https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/eval.1p.html

The eval utility shall construct a command by concatenating
arguments together, separating each with a  character.
The constructed command shall be read and executed by the shell.

Example:
> foo=10 x=foo
> echo '$'$x
$foo
> eval echo '$'$x
10

> d='/tmp/dir' e='doc,docx,pdf'
> echo "$d/"*.{"$e"}
/tmp/dir/*.{doc,docx,pdf}
> eval echo "$d/"*.{"$e"}
/tmp/dir/a.doc /tmp/dir/b.docx /tmp/dir/c.pdf


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
